# Copying Primary Contact to New Opportunity with Flow/PB

Tags: visual-workflow, automation

I've been able to find a good amount of resources for copying contact roles to opportunities. [This one](https://judisohn.com/2015/04/06/using-salesforce-process-builder-flow-with-opportunity-contact-roles/) and [this one](http://www.arkusinc.com/archive/2015/opportunity-contact-roles-with-process-builder-and-flow) seem to be favorites, and while informative, aren't really registering with what I'm trying to do, exactly.

My goal: Create a process builder that will create a 'renewal' opportunity when stage = Closed Won. The new opportunity should copy over usual fields (amount, term, start/end dates, etc), but it should also copy over the **Primary Contact** from the original opportunity.

I'm having a difficult time figuring what variables I need to set in the Flow, and also how to pull the primary contact from the original opportunity in the process builder. I've attached screenshots.

Process Builder works in creating the new opp, but I can't figure out how to pull primary contact from the original opp.

I know I'm missing some elements. Could point me in the right direction of how many elements do I need/am I missing? Is my process builder at least structured right, etc?

Thanks

Process Builder [image: overview]

[image: Renwal Opp immediate action fields to update]

Immediate Action for 'Add Primary Contact' [image]

Flow framework:

[image: do I need more elements?]

Contact ID + Opp ID variable framework:

[image]

[image]

Comment: the primaryContact can be found on the Opportunity's child related list OpportunityContactRoles

Comment: @cropredy Thank you. Am I creating a new record using that object in the flow?

Comment: yes, you will need to find the OCR on the original Oppo then insert a new OCR on the renewal Oppo

Comment: Got it. So ONE process buider and ONE flow. From a workflow perspective it would be...process builder that creates renewal upon closed won, then process builder calls on the flow? And then as far as the flow is concerned it would have how many elements (not including 'start')? 1) Get Records element (opp ID + contact ID) 2) Get records elemetn (Original Contact Role ID + 'is primary' = true, 3) Create Contact Role record on new Opp?

Comment: mostly right; step 2) also needs to filter by `origOppoId` as otherwise you'll get all OCRs for all Oppos that are primary

Comment: @cropredy are there any 'Assignment' elements, or is it just 1) Get Records  and store OppID + ContactID store in 2 new variables...2) Get records OCR ID store in new variable...3)Create record on OppContactRole of new contact role?

Comment: You have to create a variable of type Record (sobject) for the OCR and then assign vale’s from the Getrecords OCR and renewal oppo record id

Comment: @cropredy okay, so three elements all together? No Assignments elements? (working in new lighting flow btw)

Comment: At this point, I think you should try it and refer to Trailhead when you get stuck as there are modules that deal with creating sobjects.

Comment: @cropredy Will do. I've been going off this one: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/business_process_automation/business_process_automation_combined. If you have any other rec's I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do this:

[image]

Two inputs:

- `oppoId` (comes from Process Builder)
- `renewalOppoId` (comes from Process Builder - *assumes you construct the Renewal Oppo before invoking the Flow*)

[image]

Three use cases

- Oppo has a Primary OCR
- Oppo has OCR but none primary
- Oppo has no OCR

The Decision block tests for a value in the fetched `oppoPrimaryOCR.Id` record variable. If null, then no OCR was found for the Oppo or no primary OCR was found.

It helps to understand the gestalt of Lightning Flow when it comes to sobjects:

- Pass in variables that are Ids of records
- Fetch sobjects into record variables; enumerate the fields you care about in the Get Records element
- Use assignment statements to create new variables, also of type record, to set values in the record to be inserted, either by copying values from a fetched record variable or by using a formula.
- Use a Create Record element to insert new sobjects
- Use consistent naming conventions.

Now the above only scratches the surface for Lightning Flow but it should help organize your thoughts.

The debug output illustrates how the blocks are built

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks so much for this level of detail. I should be to go off this assuming I set up the process builder to just create a new renewal opp. Really appreciate it .